# How do I graph the non-relapse mortality?

Tags: survival

According to the EBMT, Non relapse mortality (NRM) is the time to deaths without relapse/recurrence (after for example a stem cell transplantation for leukemia.). Deaths from any cause without prior progression are events. Events related to the disease such as relapse or progression are competing events, loss to follow‐up are censored.

I'd like to create graphs like for example the following, which compares NRM in patients with and without AKI:

[image: Non-relapse mortality]

(From: Impact of Acute Kidney Injury on Long Term Mortality after Nonmyeloablative Hematopoietic Cell Transplantation, Parikh et al.)

What method do I use for this? Am I right in assuming that the Kaplan Meier estimator won't work here?